# Insert data in table using drupal form alter submit

Tags: forms

I am currently work with a drupal's inbuilt form which is coming from it's system function.
Now I added a extra field with value in the form with Drupal's custommodule_form_deal_node_form_alter(). 
It is working perfectly. 
But my problem is How to insert the value in the database with the default form's value. As the form's has its own default submit function.  I know it may be done using custommodule_form_deal_node_form_alter_submit($form,$form_state)
But dont know how to merge my value with the default form's submit function.
Please help me.

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you trying to do; can you try explaining in other words please?

Answer (score 2):

In your alter hook you can create custom submit handlers.
Ex.

```
function custommodule_form_deal_node_form_alter() {
    if (isset($form['actions']['submit'])) {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit';
      }
    }
```

then you implement the custom submit handlers.

```
function custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
 // $form_state will have the form value which you can insert into database.
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But my question is the default form is inserting its own value to table. like id, name, address etc. Now I want to update my barcode value(this field I altered in the form) against the id. for that how to get the id in the the altered submit function? If I get the id in  `function custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {}` then I can update the database table.

Comment: Can you do print_r($form_state); and see. i think it should give you all the values.

Comment: I tried this.
`function custommodule_form_deal_node_form_alter_submit($form,$form_state){
$barcodeval=$form_state['values']['barcodeVal'];
$sku=$form_state['values']['field_product']['und']['form']['sku'];
$created=$form_state['values']['created'];;
db_query("update commerce_product set barcode_val='".$barcodeval."' where sku='".$sku."' and created=".$created);
}`. But database table is not updated with the barcode value. Am I doing it right? Is there any way using which I can use the insert command to insert the barcode value with form's default insert action insstead of update query?

Answer (score 0):

For a node form you'll want to hook into the submit button, which is in the actions container:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_foo_submit';
```